# Dyck type lattice paths bounded between the lines $y=x$ and $y=x+k$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

**Question:** For $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$, let $a_{n,k}$ denote the number of lattice paths starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(n,n)$, with allowed steps $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, such that all points $(x,y)$ on the path satisfy $x\leq y\leq x+k$.

Let $A_k(t)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_{n,k}t^n$. Find a recurrence relation for $A_k(t)$, $k\geq 1$. Hence, or otherwise, prove that $$A_k(t)=\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor\tfrac{k}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{m}\binom{k-m}{m}t^m}{\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor\tfrac{k+1}{2}\rfloor}(-1)^{m}\binom{k+1-m}{m}t^m}.$$

**Approach:** Let $L_k$ be such a lattice path that stays between $y=x$ and $y=k+k$. Like in the standard "Catalan" case, lets break $L_k$ apart at the point it meets the line $y=x$. We observe that each valid $L_k$ path can be broken into a sequence of paths of the form $$\{N\}\times L_{k-1} \times \{E\}.$$ Where $L_{k-1}$ is a path that stays below the line $y=x+k-1$ (because of the already taken initial $N$ step) Thus, we obtain the recurrence relation for the generating series $$A_k(t)=\frac{1}{1-tA_{k-1}(t)}.$$ Any idea how can I get the formula above from this recurrence relation other than induction?

Comment: Hint: It is the same method to finding the Catalan number generating function, interpreted as counting Dyck paths. Consider the last time that such a path touches the line $y=x$.

Comment: I don't follow, how do I deal with this upper $y=x+k$ line?

Comment: Have you seen the proofs [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/catalan-numbers/#recurrence-relation-generating-function), both the proof of a recurrence relation for $C_n$, and how that recurrence relation implies a generating function equation? If not, please read. Then, think about how to apply a similar strategy to this situation.

Comment: I've edited the question adding an approach trying to follow what you are suggesting... Either I don't understand what you are getting at or you are suggesting that these are in fact also counted by the Catalan numbers?

Comment: You are getting close! Two comments. (1) While $L$ must stay between the lines $y=x$ and $y=x+k$, the smaller paths $L_i$ must stay between $y=x+1$ and $y=k$. Effectively, these smaller paths are counted by $A_{k-1}(t)$, which lets you get a recurrence.

Comment: (2) The tricky part: the placement of the $t$ your equation is incorrect. Here is the sentence you need to translate into generating functions:$\tag*{}$ "A path with height at most $k$ is a _sequence_ objects of the form $\{N,E\}\times L_i$, where $L_i$ is a path with height at most $k-1$." $\tag*{}$ Think of the $\{N,E\}$ part as the $\{\bullet\}$ in combinatorial species; the $\{N,E\}$ part is a like path from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, so it has a "weight" of $1$.

Comment: (1) yes, I thought this might be the case.. thinking in the (rotated picture) where we have NE and SW steps from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,0)$ that stay above $0$ and have height less than $k$ perhaps makes this more obvious... (2) thanks, yeah I knew something was off with my generating function. I think I see where you are going now... thanks so much for your help and patience. Also... https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/PEART/pwatjis2.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109417/discussion-between-connor-and-mike-earnest).